# Choosing a subject to create a site for

Tags: marketing, best-practices, recommendations, research

For 6 years I'm working as web developer and I would like to finally create my own site. I thought I have everything needed: programming and administration skills, found a good designer, own servers and understanding how to operate site. But I've missed very important (or the most important) point: how do I find a subject for my site? My hobby and my work are the same: IT, but I don't want to create just another tech blog or news aggregator, I want something different.

First I thought things like [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/) or [Google top 1000](http://www.google.com/adplanner/static/top1000/) could help, but I've got lost in thousands of options I can't see them all (I actually can, but it'll take at least a couple of month).

So my question is: how did you start? Where did you get the idea?

Comment: So, you are asking "where do people get ideas from?" People get ideas from their own experiences, interests, knowledge and imagination. Needless to say this is an area that is as vast as the universe is large. This isn't the sort of thing that can be succinctly answered on a Q&A site.

Comment: If you don't want a topic that you're experienced in (tech), the next best thing is to pick a topic that you're very interested in learning more about. Personal interest is very important or you'll find it difficult to keep it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with your site. If you want to make money online, you can find a good niche. Try to browse the affiliate networks niches (http://www.wolf-howl.com/affiliate-marketing/the-affiliate-marketing-newbies-guide-to-finding-niches/).

But this may not be what you're looking for. You may as well create a blog about your life.